# Is it possible to use PHP readfile() with a file on a different server?

Tags: php, download

Can I use the PHP code below if the PDF file is not on my server but on a different server with a different IP? If not, what's the best replacement?

This code fragment was taken from this PHP tutorial: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Simple-and-Secure-PHP-Download-Script-with-Limits-Tutorial/

```
//Define the content type and show force download attachment dialog

header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="http://www.yourdomain.com/ebookfordownloads/ebook.pdf"');

//Stream the PDF file for downloading using PHP readfile function
//The readfile is using absolute server path
//You can determine this path by uploading a php script to the folder containing the download material.
/*
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
?>
*/
readfile("/your/absolute/server/path/html/ebookfordownloads/ebook.pdf");
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php: *A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.*

Comment: use file_get_contents('url') instead... but it has to be enabled

Comment: @Jeff care to point out which of the reasons given in "Not a Real Question" apply here. I assume (and agree) its because the answer is given in the manual and thus "rhetorical", but some authority argument for future reference would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use the PHP code below if the PDF file is not on my server but on a different server with a different IP? If not what is the best replacement?

Yes, that would be possible, depending on your servers settings. It will have to allow connections to other servers ([`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) should be true) to do so. Other than that, you're golden ;)

Comment: Thanks. In this case i need to pass the full http URL to readfile? Like for example `readfile("http://download.remoteserver.com/pdf/ebook.pdf")`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fopen wrappers work with readfile, too, unless the administrator set [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) to false. You may want to supply the `$context` parameter to fine-tune the [HTTP behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).